# Determine maximum network throughput?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

Is there a concrete way to determine the maximum throughput of a network?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measuring_network_throughput) gives the following formula

Throughput <= RWIN/RTT

where RWIN is TCP received and RTT is TCP round trip time.

Is there a way of "asking" the network how much bandwidth is allocated to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the tools at this site to measure bandwidth. https://iperf.fr/